# Find path where Joomla! is installed on the server

Tags: joomla, graphical-logo

I'm new to website maintenance.

I'm currently using Joomla! with the momentum template and would like to change the template logo. As I understand it I need to replace the current logo file, which can be found in /templates/rt_momentum_j15/images/logo/dark.

I'm using JCE File Browser (through the control panel) to peruse the files on the server. There is no 'templates' folder in the root, and I believe this folder can be found where Joomla! is installed.

How can I find where Joomla is installed on the server so I can access the templates folder?

EDIT: screenshot of directory structure as seen through JCE File Browser:

[image: screenshot of directory structure as seen through JCE File Browser]

Comment: if possible then plz add a screenshoot of your site directory structure that displayed by `JCE File Browser`. And what version of joomla u are using?

Comment: I am using Joomla 2.5, screenshot has been added

Comment: As per your screenshot I think it shows only images folder, you have to go one level up for find the template folder, because template folder is within the joomla, you are in the correct way but just need to go one level up.

Comment: @BugalugsNash you have to use any FTP client to get the template folder, with JCE you can't achieve your requirement.

Comment: @pkachhia This screenshot shows the root folder - I don't think I can go any higher than that level

Comment: @BugalugsNash this root folder means your roots `images` folder, you can't access your other roots files or directory with JCE

Comment: you would need to use ftp or go to your filesystem via control panel or ssh etc.

Comment: Oh! Ok that makes sense. Next problem is - I've downloaded FileZilla to try ftp (which I've never used before) and can't connect. I use the same username and password that I use to get into Joomla for the site (which is what online research suggests is what I need to do), but I keep getting the error "530 Login authentication failed". This is a nightmare!

Comment: Have you checked template manager from the menu into joomla for any setting regarding logo?

Comment: @pkachhia yes that was the first thing I tried, but there is only a setting as to where the logo is displayed, nothing for changing the logo itself. It tells me there that I need to replace the logo file to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download a File Manager such as Filezilla (which I see you have already done).

The username and password to connect are not the same as the admin password. With your host should come a control panel such as cPanel which allows you to add FTP users, however most hosts have a File Manager withing the control panel which will allow you to maintain files.

Else you can download [File Management](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/file-management) extension from JED which will act as an FTP in the Joomla backend.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can also give the [eXtplorer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/file-management/2630) plugin for Joomla a try.